# how to make netjukebox work without winamp

Tags: streaming, media, home-server, wamp

I found this tutorial on the internet and I'm disappointed because it needs winamp to work. Anyone in here who have tried this one without using winamp? Or do you have any tutorial that can turn a home pc into a server so that I can access my files anywhere

Comment: please reformulate your question: The unknown tutorial part is useless. Which netjukebox features do you need? What's the os of your home pc? do you need smartphone support? which kind of files (videos, audio, photos, any)?

Comment: oh yes I forgot to put the link. But I already found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understand you want to stream your medias from your home pc, and effectively netjukebox needs winamp but they are plenty of solutions to do it without winamp:

- **stream audio** by an **external site**, Win2k or later: http://jukefly.com/
- **stream any medias** by an **external site**, WinXP SP2 or later/Mac OS X Intel: http://www.orb.com/
- **store (and access)** your music **online**: http://www.mp3tunes.com/ or http://www.audiobox.fm/
- **stream audio** by **your own site**:

  - java so multi-platform but heavy on memory: [Sockso](http://sockso.pu-gh.com/) or [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp)
  - Win2k or later (or Wine): [vibe streamer](http://www.vibestreamer.com/)
  - advanced, need a php/mysql server, support video: [Ampache](http://ampache.org/)

If you choose to use your own site, maybe you will need to open your router and/or your firewall, and to use [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) if you haven't a static IP

Answer (score 0):

For streaming you can use almost **any media player**.
Winamp is only required for local playback with playlist support.